# Leave approval hierarchy in openERP

Tags: odoo

I am new to openERP and facing issues with HR module.

I have this structure

Project Manager-Team Leader-Developer

1. Team Leader is a manager of developer
2. Project Manager is manager of Team Leader.

So, if developer asks for leave then first leave request should be sent to Team Leader (mail notification to Team Leader and Project Manager) and once TL approves Leave then automaitically request sent to Project Manager for second level approval.

With openERP 6.1, there is no possibility to approve leave by Team Leader unless and until Team Leader is specified as a HR manager which is inappropriate.

Anybody have any solution then let me know. Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

I would hide the manager field for all except for user role  'config' Then you
can make the correct relation and trigger  the work flow as per your need.

Option 2:

The xml work flow will be handled by a def. You can override it  and put a if
statement there. This would take a bit longer then the prev one.

If you are still need help ping me